# Installing Python 3.5.6.1: python contains a recursive dependency on itself:

Tags: macos, install, homebrew, python

I am trying to install Python 3.5.6.1 with:

```
$ brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/f2a764ef944b1080be64bd88dca9a1d80130c558/Formula/python.rb
$ brew switch python 3.6.5_1
```

But this gives the following error:

```
==> Consider using `brew extract python ...`!
This will extract your desired python version to a stable tap instead of
installing from an unstable URL!

######################################################################## 100.0%
Error: python contains a recursive dependency on itself:
  python depends on sphinx-doc
  sphinx-doc depends on python
```

How can I install it ?

Comment: Hi @xela56!  Would you be considering alternatives like Conda? https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/#download-section https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands

Answer (score 0):

You can download any python version directly from [the python website](https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/) and install it manually. As you're trying to use a specific version, I'm guessing that you're not planning on upgrading it later. That way you can keep both versions if you want.